# Running an ARM OS(CooCox) on X86 using qemu

Tags: arm, emulation, cross-compiling, qemu, coocox

I am new to qemu and have a board that uses the STM32F4103 processor. There is a program on it that runs on CooOS. I want to simulate the embedded code on an X86 machine and believe qemu is the way. Am i on the right path ?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: **YES**. A nice starting point would arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain it comes with examples with Cortex-M3 for qemu platform..

**gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4\share\gcc-arm-none-eabi\samples**

https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded